Is there a way to resample non-UTC data in Pandas Dataframe?
In order to be able to resample the time index in a Pandas Dataframe, one has to change the index to datetime using this following line:
pd.index = pd.to_datetime(pd.index, utc=True)

However, this is not correct in my case, because the time is not UTC. And I want it to stay that way. Is there a way to resample non-UTC data? I want to resample the time from 1min to 10min.
Here is how my pd looks:


It would be easier to help if there was some sample data to recreate the issue.

You don't need to set utc=True.

I get an error if I leave out utc=True in the line above: ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True.
And utc=False generates an error as well.
